# jQuery checkbox checked then color change of a ul

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have two radiobuttons. The first one is checked when you come on the page. Then the first list underneath that radiobutton is visible (black text color). The second list and the text of the second radiobutton is grey.

When a user will check the second radiobutton the 2 lists must be visible (both black text color). And radiobutton 1 text must be in grey color then.

When a user is switch back from 2 to 1 see above... :-)

i hope somewone can help me with this? :)

**HTML**:

```
 <div id="order-number">
      <div class="split"><input type="radio" name="number" value="5" checked>text</div>
      <div class="split"><input type="radio" name="number" value="10">text</div>
 </div>

 <div id="order-list">
      <ul>
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $uls = $('#order-list > ul'), $chks = $('#order-number input:checkbox');
$chks.change(function(){
    var idx = $chks.index(this);
    $uls.eq(idx).css('opacity', this.checked ? 1 : .5)
}).change()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dKb5G/)

Comment: Arun, thnx! Its almost good. When you select the second checkbox the to lists must be black. (stupit me: it must be radiobuttons and the code will not change back when i change the checkboxes in radiobuttons)

Comment: @Maanstraat you mean http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dKb5G/4/

Comment: With the radios yes. But: radio 1 is checked list one is black. When radio 2 is checked list one and list two must be black.

Comment: @Maanstraat like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dKb5G/5/